# Spring security, after login button pressed, j_spring_security_check not found is shown

Tags: spring-security

I have implemented Spring security with custom login form. Interestingly it is working in my locally deployed application but when deployed to hostgator server, example.com/j_spring_security_check not found is shown in the browser. Anyone has experienced the same issue? Please help.

Comment: You will find lots of other questions on this if you search the site. Please read the answers and if it still doesn't work, expand your question to explain why they don't apply.

Comment: I have gone through every single one of them. All related issues doesn't work even on the local machine. In my case, it works locally but not in the server. I wonder, there should be some sort of settings for the live environment for hostgator...